# Left join with count() and show matches separately within table

Tags: sqlite, group-by, count, left-join, qgis

I counted birds on different dates and areas. Some birds got a tracking ID.
That gives my a table with this header. `t1`:

```
SPECIES | AGE | BIRD_TRACKING_ID | AREA | DATE_1
------------------------------------------------
        |     |                  |      |
```

Then we observated the birds and made a record of the trees they landed on. Every tree got an unique ID. One bird could have visited none, one ore several trees. That gives me table `t2` with this header:

```
TREE |DESCR  |TREE_ID |BIRD_ID
------------------------------
     |       |        |
```

```
CREATE TABLE birds (
    SPECIES varchar(255),
    AGE varchar(255),
    BIRD_TRACKING_ID varchar(255),
    AREA varchar(255),
    DATE_1 date
);

INSERT INTO birds (SPECIES, AGE, BIRD_TRACKING_ID, AREA, DATE_1)
VALUES ('eagle',    'ad',  null,      'A03', '2021-06-02'),
       ('merl',     'ad', 'B_mer_01', 'A03', '2021-07-01'),
       ('owl',      'jv',  null,      'A04', '2021-06-11'),
       ('penguin',  'jv', 'B_pen_21', 'A04', '2021-07-01'),
       ('eagle',    'juv', null,      'A03', '2021-06-15'),
       ('eagle',    'ad', 'B_eag_16', 'A02', '2021-06-02'),
       ('merl',     'ad',  null,      'A03', '2021-08-01'),
       ('owl',      'jv', 'B_owl_01', 'A02', '2021-02-01'),
       ('penguin',  'jv', 'B_pen_23', 'A04', '2021-04-17'),
       ('penguin',  'jv',  null,      'A01', '2021-07-15'),
       ('eagle',    'ad', 'B_eag_23', 'A01', '2021-04-11'),
       ('eagle',    'ad', 'B_eag_11', 'A03', '2021-01-01')
;


CREATE TABLE trees (
    TREE varchar(255),
    DESCR varchar(255),
    TREE_ID varchar(255),
    BIRD_ID varchar(255)
);

INSERT INTO trees (TREE, DESCR, TREE_ID, BIRD_ID)
VALUES ('oak tree', 'd', 'T_2021_1a', 'B_eag_11'),
       ('birch',    'v', 'T_2021_2a', 'B_mer_01'),
       ('oak tree', 'v', 'T_2021_3a', 'B_owl_01'),
       ('larch',    'v', 'T_2021_4a', 'B_pen_23'),
       ('larch',    'v', 'T_2021_5d', 'B_pen_23'),
       ('birch',    'd', 'T_2021_5a', 'B_eag_11')
;
```

What I want is to count all birds species grouped by area and species. That's simple so far.
But in a next step I want to get the tree ID from `t2`. I did this:

```
select 
  B_spec,
  AMOUNT,
  TREE,
  B_age,
  B_age_juv,
  B_age_ad,
  B_track, 
  B_area, 
  date1
  from(
    select
      SPECIES as B_spec, 
      count(SPECIES) as AMOUNT,
      AGE as B_age,
      count(case when AGE = 'juv' then 1 end) as B_age_juv,
      count(case when AGE = 'ad' then 1 end) as B_age_ad,
      BIRD_TRACKING_ID as B_track, 
      AREA as B_area, 
      DATE_1 as date1,
      group_concat(TREE_ID) as TREE
    from birds
    left join trees t2
    on BIRD_TRACKING_ID = t2.BIRD_ID
    group by B_area, B_spec
    order by B_spec asc
    ) t1
```

and got that:
[image: output]
Obviously it is messed up and the counts are wrong.

What I want is in field `TREE` all the tree IDs of the trees that has been visited by that bird.
Furthermore it would be nice to have a count of a specific bird species in one row and in another the bird that has visited a tree.

For example on area `A03` I had 3 eagles. 2 with no tracking ID, one with tracking ID. So the output for the 3 eagles on A03 should be:

```
B_spec  |TREE                |AMOUNT| B_age_juv   |B_age_ad  |B_area |date1
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
eagle   |null                |2     | 1           |1         |A03    |2021-06-02
eagle   |T_2021_1a,T_2021_5a |1     | 0           |1         |A03    |2021-01-01
```

The date should be the first date when observed a bird of that species on that specifiic area. Eagles on A3 without a tracking ID were seen on 2021-06-02 and 2021-06-15. So the first row has 2021-06-02 as `date1`.

The data is not realistic, penguins are flightless. And I can use only SQLite in QGIS.

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/fd7b29/1/0)

Comment: The date should be the first date when observed a bird of that species on that specifiic area. Eagles on A3 without a tracking ID were seen on 2021-06-02 and 2021-06-15. So the first row has 2021-06-02 as `date1`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should create one more grouping level for the birds without `BIRD_TRACKING_ID` and use conditional aggregation:

```
SELECT b.SPECIES B_spec, 
       GROUP_CONCAT(t.TREE_ID) TREE,
       COUNT(DISTINCT b.rowid) AMOUNT,
       COUNT(DISTINCT CASE WHEN AGE = 'juv' THEN b.rowid END) B_age_juv,
       COUNT(DISTINCT CASE WHEN AGE = 'ad' THEN b.rowid END) B_age_ad,
       b.AREA B_area,
       MIN(b.DATE_1) date1
FROM birds b LEFT JOIN trees t
ON b.BIRD_TRACKING_ID = t.BIRD_ID
GROUP BY B_area, B_spec, b.BIRD_TRACKING_ID IS NOT NULL
ORDER BY B_spec;
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlite_3.27&fiddle=634580733371d626bbb7ca9571efc949).

Comment: At first I thought it doesn't work, but then I recognized that I messed up the age (2 values for juvenile). Your solution is what I needed. But what is the reason to use `rowid`?

Comment: @EndorCartographer The column rowid is the only way to distinguish different birds because some of them have no BIRD_TRACKING_ID.